# Как очистить историю выбора реквизитов в 1С

Tags: 1с

Есть конфигурация и в ней добавляются реквизиты созданные в табличную часть.
Удалил некоторые, но после они также предлагаются из списка историй уже добавленных до этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И выходит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда просто отключил, чтобы до этого добавленные не предлагались вовсе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно полностью пофиксить это?

Answer (score 0):

Если логически вам в данном поле не нужна история, то лучше просто [отключить её](https://its.1c.ru/db/v8std#content:744:hdoc). А по очистке [посмотрите тут](https://forum.infostart.ru/forum9/topic114510/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Процедура ОчисититьИсторию()
    ТекущийПользователь = ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.ТекущийПользователь();
    ХранилищеСистемныхНастроек.Удалить("ИсторияВыбора",,ТекущийПользователь.Имя);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Хранилище системных настроек хранит историю в ключе "ИсторияВыбора".

Comment: Таким способом случайно не очистит историю выбора для всех полей?

Comment: Честно говоря использовать не приходилось, но автора понимаю: желание очистить историю выбора возникает при отладке, для практического использования - редко, поэтому очистить всю историю не должно быть проблемой. В СП можно найти ```СтандартноеХранилищеНастроекМенеджер```, там по ссылке "Настройки, автоматически сохраняемые в системном хранилище" есть информация о ключах настроек.